# MySQL insert position value

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have trouble while inserting the values corresponding to a column: `position`. I have multiple inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO category_product(id_category,id_product,position) VALUES(2,1,1);
INSERT INTO category_product(id_category,id_product,position) VALUES(2,2,2);
INSERT INTO category_product(id_category,id_product,position) VALUES(2,3,3);
INSERT INTO category_product(id_category,id_product,position) VALUES(3,1,0);
INSERT INTO category_product(id_category,id_product,position) VALUES(3,3,1);
```

But I would like to have something like an insert within a select, I've tried:

```
SET @position := 0;
INSERT INTO category_product(id_category,id_product,position) 
(SELECT 2,id_product,@position+1 FROM product);

SET @position := -1;
INSERT INTO category_product(id_category,id_product,position) 
(SELECT 3,id_product,@position+1 FROM product WHERE [a condition to get id_product 1, 3]);
```

My problem: it doesn't work like I want and my main reason for this is I'm using a loop to make all the inserts (using a Cursor) and they're just killing me with the time. Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some days passed, I've checked my queries and got my mistake: Wrong use of [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

As this: `@position+1` give me always `1` because it's not an increasing value, it's just the same variable `+1`... in order to make it an increasing value it must be assigned the new increased value: `@position := @position+1`

```
SET @position := 0;
INSERT INTO category_product(id_category,id_product,position) 
(SELECT 2,id_product,@position := @position+1 FROM product);

SET @position := -1;
INSERT INTO category_product(id_category,id_product,position) 
(SELECT 3,id_product,@position := @position+1 FROM product 
  WHERE [a condition to get id_product 1, 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Auto Increment Position Column when you Create product TABLE

EXAMPLE

```
               Create Table category_product
               ( 
              id_category int,
              id_product int,
               position int Auto_Increment=1
               )
```

Then Simple Insert

```
    Insert into category_product
     select 2,id_product from Product
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not right syntax, you'll need `position` as a primary key and I'll edit my question in order to clarify that `position` would have different sequences